# Cleaning up QList and QGraphicsScene to avoid memory leaks

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qgraphicsscene, qlist

I want to be thorough and clean up to avoid memory and object leaks.

I had the misunderstanding that Qt cleans automatically objects that go out of scope, except pointers need to be deleted manually.

In my code I have a number of `QList`... example:

```
void someFunction()
{
    QList<int> x = QList<int>() << 0 << 0 << 0 << 0;
    QList<QImage> y; // filled in some way
    QList<QGraphicsScene*> s;

    s = otherFunction(x, y);
}

QList<QGraphicsScene*> otherFunction(QList<int>& x, const QList<QImage>& y)
{
    QList<QGraphicsScene*> s; 
    s.push_back(this->scene());  // a few times; of course there is some processing...
    return s;
}

void thirdFunction()
{
    QList<int> x = QList<int>() << 0 << 0 << 0 << 0;
    QList<QImage> y; // filled in some way
    QList<QGraphicsScene*> s;

    s = otherFunction(x, y);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        view[i]->setScene(s.at(i)); // view is a QList<QGraphicsView*>
    }
}
```

Called multiple times, I can see the memory increasing (seen from task manager).

Obviously when items go out of scope, they are not being deleted... I immediately suspected the list of scene pointers.

1) What is the best way to delete them ? Will

```
qDeleteAll(s);
```

in `someFunction()` be enough ? Will it delete the scene pointers, as well as all the `QGraphicItems` inside the scenes ? or do I need to iterate through the list of scenes, and delete all items ? Do I have to do this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        s.at(i).clear();
    } // then
    qDeleteAll(s);
```

2) Do I need to delete the lists of simple variables (`int`, `bool`) ?
What about lists of objects, like `QImage` ?

3) I assumed that removing an item from the scene deletes its pointer. But now I read that, after removing an item from the scene, it needs to be deleted manually. So does

```
scene().clear();
```

delete the `QGraphicItem` pointers that have been added to the scene ? Or should the items be deleted as well using a `delete` call ?

**4)** In the `thirdFunction`, do I have a memory leak ? It seems like I do !!
I can't delete the scenes since I set them onto views... but what happens to the scenes that were assigned to the views already ?
How do I clean that correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**
`qDeleteAll` deletes items in a container using the C++ `delete` operator. It's also stated in the Qt documentation about `QGraphicsScene` destructor:

> Removes and deletes all items from the scene object before destroying
>   the scene object

So it's enough to call `qDeleteAll(s)`.

**2.**
There is no need to delete lists of basic or Qt types like `QList<int>` or `QList<QImage>` as they are deleted when the list is deleted.

**3.**
`QGraphicsScene::clear()` removes and deletes all items from the scene. So calling `scene().clear();` is enough. It's equivalent to calling :

```
qDeletaAll( scene()->items() );
```

**4.**
Since a view does not take ownership of scene, you should delete the previously assigned scenes using `deleteLater()` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
{
    view[i]->scene()->deleteLater();
    view[i]->setScene(s.at(i)); // view is a QList<QGraphicsView*>
}
```